# AWS DynamoDb: Does KeySchema create internal index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

For Dynamodb, Does setting KeySchema automatically create a primary index?  Or need to use GlobalSecondaryIndexes to create index?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no primary index on a DynamoDB table. Setting the key schema creates a [primary key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey).

If your primary key is composite, i.e. comprises both a partition key and a sort key, then you can retrieve items for a given partition key ordered by the sort key.

Comment: I am just curious about how access patterns like begins_with (using a string prefix) are supported without an internal index?

Comment: The data is partitioned by the partition key and, if a sort key is present, ordered by the sort key. Yes, it's indexed internally but nowhere in the DynamoDB documentation will you see reference to a "primary index" afaik. Certainly, there's no exposed index on the partition key, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not explicitly mentioned in the documentation that an index is created for Primary KeySchema. However, if we look at the access patterns using Sort Key, it can be easily understood that an internal index is maintained for supporting access patterns like begins_with.
Checkout [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-sort-keys-to-organize-data-in-amazon-dynamodb/) for more details in access patterns using Sort keys.

Creating an alternate sort key or [local secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) also support internal index argument for Primary KeySchema with Sort Key (like an index for alternate Sort key).